# Bug: answer posted after closing the question.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

The question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132072/does-doing-mathematics-make-you-more-intelligent was closed, but 13 minutes *after* closing there was an answer posted.

I suppose this is a bug, and not a feature of the software.

Comment: Zev Chonoles' answer is correct.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Zev said "One thing" then "I believe that one thing would be out of date." which part is correct?

Comment: We allow a grace period on for adding answers to closed questions - see [this Stack Overflow Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/3) for the details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grace period when a question is closed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/grace-period-when-a-question-is-closed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be intended behavior. I remembered that there was a [similar occurrence on MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/644/answer-to-a-closed-question/); [this meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63380/its-possible-to-answer-a-closed-question-no-matter-how-old) post is where Andrew Stacey filed the resulting bug report. Apparently the resolution was that

> We now block answering after a reasonably large amount of time has gone by.

I can imagine that 13 minutes would qualify. However, I would have thought that, now that SE pages are almost-real-time updating with comments, answers, votes, etc. that the above answer would be out of date and that closure would take effect immediately, without someone having to reload the page.

Comment: Yes, I was aware to the MO threads, but I figured that the software on MO is very outdated and the problem was corrected on SE 2.x versions.