# Grace period when a question is closed

Tags: feature-request, closing, answers, closed-questions, grace-period

Didn't there use to be a grace period of 5 minutes after a question was closed where answers could still be submitted, but where one can't *start* writing an answer? If there wasn't (and I have just dreamed that the feature existed), shouldn't there be?

I was almost done writing a medium-long answer to [Why is there no Nobel Prize in math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169556/why-is-there-no-nobel-prize-in-math) when I got a notification that the question had been closed and I couldn't submit it. This was, according to the site, only 2 minutes after the closure.

(It is not my intention to discuss whether this question *should* have been closed. I thought it was a reasonable enough question that we should provide an answer. But that was before the asker added boldface lines to his question with subjective arguments that there *should* have been a Nobel in math).

Comment: I ran into the same problem a few minutes ago. Spent 15 minutes crafting an answer, only to have it vanish. Very frustrating.

Comment: @Rick This has happened to me countless times. I think it is one of the most annoying aspects of the software platform. Given that it highly discourages many valued members, I am baffled why they don't fix it so that answers started before closure can be posted.

Comment: I experienced this recently with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901642/on-the-rotation-of-points, following which the asker reposted (I didn't ask him to do that) the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901691/on-the-rotation-of-points-issue/1901698 and I gratefully entered my answer before the new thread got locked. Unfortunately, this has engendered a little argument in the comments. I think the grace period is very important, and perhaps it should take the form of a timer you can keep clicking to get an extension to put the finishing touches.

Answer (score 5):

There is (was?) a grace period, but there's a small part of its operation which you missed. For reference, see [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed).

The grace period (from the above link, 4 hours) kicks in only when:

- The question is closed.
- You started composing an answer before the question was closed.
- **And** the client-side notification telling you that the question was closed (and locking out the submit button) fails (for whatever reason: network connectivity, database problems, etc.)

In your description you clearly received the client-side notification. Which means that the grace period no longer applies.

Comment: Yes, that explains my experience. Anyone have some client-side magic that will block the notifications such that one doesn't risk having rugs pulled out under one's answers like that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Temporarily disable Javascript. The web developer toolbar for Firefox has an easy command for that, for example.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Well, that would also disable the preview. Always editing answers blind because the questions might be closed at some time would be a worse cure than the disease here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Maybe also enable Chatjax! Maybe that requires javascript :(