# I answered a question that was on hold

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533531/limits-that-approach-zero/533672#533672) question, and I had started writing my answer, but then once I posted it I noticed the question had been put on hold, and was wondering: Why can you still answer on hold questions? It seems rather counter intuitive (or at least ineffective) that such questions can still be answered, although I am glad my time wasn't wasted on that answer.

Comment: Other related posts: [Grace period when a question is closed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4625), [How did this closed question gain a new answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34931) and [Bug: answer posted after closing the question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3985). And on [meta.se]: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a question is put on hold, the button to add a new answer is removed. However, if you've already clicked that button and started writing an answer, the process is allowed to conclude.  This is similar to why an answer to a question on hold can be edited.

**Update:**
Tim Post says that if [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) are operating properly, a periodic message is sent to the browser that should disable the "Submit" button. Sometimes, WebSockets fail (or are not supported by the browser), and the "Submit" button remains enabled, even after the question is closed.

Comment: Actually you can post an answer if you haven't received the notice that the answer is on hold. I'm not sure how it works exactly, but there is a mechanism which separates some answers from others.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If the page has not been refreshed since the hold, then it will still have a "Your Answer" box and the "Post Your Answer" button. Given that, I think we are in agreement.

Comment: I recall, from my limited brain memory experience, that sometimes the top-page notice will appear that a question was closed (or put on hold), in which case no more answers can be posted, even if you have that... scared button.

Comment: Isn't this something "new"? I seem to recall a time or two where I started writing an answer that wasn't accepted because the question had been closed.

Comment: I believe that I was answering a question that was put on hold as I was writing and the answer was posted. Now it could be that I was only editing an answer that was already posted and I am misremembering. I will ask.

Comment: Thanks for this bit. I don't think this has ever happened to me. OTOH I have on a few occasions started adding an answer or a comment to a question/answer that was deleted while I was typing. There the behavior is different (=adding anything is impossible).