# How is it possible to answer a question after closure?

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879290/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-digits-in-277232917-1), as of writing, was closed 1 hour ago.

[image]

However, an answer was given 51 minutes ago.

[image]

After the question was closed, I could not see an 'Answer' button, yet, a user managed to overcome this. Usually, there would be an orange bar at the top saying 'No more answers are accepted.' and the 'Post your Answer' button would be greyed out.

How can this be possible?

Comment: For ease of lookup, [link to the post's timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2879290/timeline)

Comment: The only way I know to bring up the timeline is to manually edit the URL.

Comment: I've been on meta for a long time, so I've had chances to see others link to timelines. :)

Comment: More importantly, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/bug-answer-posted-after-closing-the-question and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/grace-period-when-a-question-is-closed are related to the actual question (things might have changed since six years ago, which is why I'm not voting to close this as a duplicate).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire did you see the final bullet point in Willie's answer on the second linked thread?

Comment: Apart from the two questions linked in Asaf's comment, there are [I answered a question that was on hold](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11355) and 
[How did this closed question gain a new answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34931)