# How did this closed question gain a new answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, closing, closed-questions

I closed a question (“ [Transposing matrices by multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4485292) ”) some hours ago as a dupe, but someone gave it a new answer two hours later. Looking at the revision history, the question had not been reopened. How could that happen?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/1218938

Comment: @BeKind That settles it. Thanks.

Comment: Some related posts on this site: [Grace period when a question is closed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4625), [I answered a question that was on hold](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11355) and [Bug: answer posted after closing the question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3985).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a cross-site duplicate of [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed/91928#91928) on global meta. This is a community wiki answer recording the accepted answer there.

---

If a question is closed while you're answering on the full version of the site, you will receive a notification that the question was closed and the 'Post Your Answer' button will be disabled. However, this is only a client-side restriction, so it is possible in some cases that this process fails.

When it does, the backend allows for a grace period of [around four hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one/79457#79457) (previously there was [no time limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63380/its-possible-to-answer-a-closed-question-no-matter-how-old)). Presumably the client-side restriction did fail in this case, and since the answer was "in-flight", as Jeff describes it, the server accepted it despite the question already having been closed.

For users answering from a mobile device, there's no client-side restriction in place to begin with, so this situation is presumably even easier to create when using the mobile version of the site.

As a side note, this apparently even works for [questions closed due to migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19208/150235). (**Editor's note:** This was fixed sometime in 2012.)